# Member action popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I wanted to do for my company's webpage, a thing where are links that belong to people, to make it when you click, you have a little menu where you can choose to send him a message or view his profile..

Before click:

[image: Before click]

After click:

[image: after click]

I tryed to search for it, couldn't find anything of much valuable.. Maybe someone can help me out.

Comment: Try something yourself first.. You can not expect someone to code for you here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for an easy way to do it, I recommend using jQuery (http://jquery.com/) with one of the popup plugins (http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/popup/). It's easy to install, and most of them have a working demo for you to test out before download.

Otherwise, coding a popup window with pure JS takes time.

This general method is to:

1. Create a hidden div
2. Position: absolute and play with the z-index so your div will be on top of all other elements.
3. Set the position to where you clicked, or somewhere around the area of the target.
4. Take into account the width and height of the window/screen. (i.e. No poing in showing a div that'll appear off screen).
5. Fill it in with information you need.
6. Make it appear.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, those steps is what I needed to know.

Comment: No problem, I could throw out a simple demo if you really need one.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done things like that in the past is to have a hidden absolute or fixed DIV layer that houses that message menu. Then have a click trigger make that div layer visible and positioned at the current mouse coordinates.

There should be a lot of articles on google telling you how to do the various stages of all those steps.